# Debugging Mapreduce on Hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop

I have a 2 node hadoop cluster and I suspect that I am getting a deadlock.

Is there a way for me to debug this and determine the root cause? Are deadlocks even possible in the Hadoop world?

The version of Hadoop is: 2.2.0-gphd-3.0.1.0

EDIT:
I am not getting any errors, the jobs are just hanging and not completing. I saw this in the logs (repeated over and over again):

> 2015-03-16 17:00:25,519 INFO [IPC Server handler 0 on 18043] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Ping from attempt_1423108525336_2110_m_000000_0
>   2015-03-16 17:00:28,522 INFO [IPC Server handler 1 on 18043] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Ping from attempt_1423108525336_2110_m_000000_0
>   2015-03-16 17:00:31,525 INFO [IPC Server handler 2 on 18043] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Ping from attempt_1423108525336_2110_m_000000_0
>   2015-03-16 17:00:34,528 INFO [IPC Server handler 3 on 18043] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Ping from attempt_1423108525336_2110_m_000000_0
>   2015-03-16 17:00:37,530 INFO [IPC Server handler 4 on 18043] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Ping from attempt_1423108525336_2110_m_000000_0
>   2015-03-16 17:00:40,533 INFO [IPC Server handler 5 on 18043] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Ping from attempt_1423108525336_2110_m_000000_0
>   2015-03-16 17:00:43,536 INFO [IPC Server handler 6 on 18043] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Ping from attempt_1423108525336_2110_m_000000_0
>   2015-03-16 17:00:46,538 INFO [IPC Server handler 7 on 18043] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Ping from attempt_1423108525336_2110_m_000000_0
>   2015-03-16 17:00:49,541 INFO [IPC Server handler 8 on 18043] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Ping from attempt_1423108525336_2110_m_000000_0
>   2015-03-16 17:00:52,600 INFO [IPC Server handler 9 on 18043] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Status update from attempt_1423108525336_2110_m_000000_0
>   2015-03-16 17:00:52,601 INFO [IPC Server handler 9 on 18043] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1423108525336_2110_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
>   2015-03-16 17:00:55,607 INFO [IPC Server handler 10 on 18043] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Ping from attempt_1423108525336_2110_m_000000_0
>   2015-03-16 17:00:58,609 INFO [IPC Server handler 11 on 18043] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Ping from attempt_1423108525336_2110_m_000000_0
>   2015-03-16 17:01:01,612 INFO [IPC Server handler 12 on 18043] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Ping from attempt_1423108525336_2110_m_000000_0
>   2015-03-16 17:01:04,614 INFO [IPC Server handler 13 on 18043] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Ping from attempt_1423108525336_2110_m_000000_0
>   2015-03-16 17:01:07,617 INFO [IPC Server handler 14 on 18043] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Ping from attempt_1423108525336_2110_m_000000_0
>   2015-03-16 17:01:10,620 INFO [IPC Server handler 15 on 18043] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Ping from attempt_1423108525336_2110_m_000000_0
>   2015-03-16 17:01:13,622 INFO [IPC Server handler 16 on 18043] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Ping from attempt_1423108525336_2110_m_000000_0
>   2015-03-16 17:01:16,625 INFO [IPC Server handler 17 on 18043] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Ping from attempt_1423108525336_2110_m_000000_0
>   2015-03-16 17:01:19,628 INFO [IPC Server handler 18 on 18043] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Ping from attempt_1423108525336_2110_m_000000_0
>   2015-03-16 17:01:22,684 INFO [IPC Server handler 19 on 18043] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Status update from attempt_1423108525336_2110_m_000000_0
>   2015-03-16 17:01:22,684 INFO [IPC Server handler 19 on 18043] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1423108525336_2110_m_000000_0 is : 1.0

Comment: What error are you getting? Be specific and provide us more details to help you

Comment: See my edit - I'm not getting any errors, just no progress in the mapreduce jobs.

Comment: Is this working with only one node?